# Passing value SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Assuming the `sDatabase = "mytable"` in string format

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test.target SELECT * FROM '" & sDatabase & "'.source"
```

This query gives me an error.

Comment: what is the error  exactly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use '' for a table name:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test.target SELECT * FROM " & sDatabase & ".source"
```